# java New class from Class<?> param

Tags: java, class, object, field, instance

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    db MC = new mymainclass();
    person Jon = MC.new person("jon", "smit", 24, "new york");
    member mJon = MC.new member(32, "jon2", "unDerground1", "25/05/2012");
    System.out.println(Jon.name + " " + mJon.ID);

    Object[] data = { "kalvin", "cleid", 30, "german" };
    Object[] data2 = { 33, "cleid", "unDerground1", "03/02/2013" };

    person Kelvin = (person) DB.newClass(data, person.class);
    member mKelvin = (member) DB.newClass(data2, member.class);

    System.out.println(Kelvin.name + " " + mKelvin.ID);

}

public Object newClass(Object[] params, Class<?> type) {

    Object ret = null;

    try {
        ret = type. newInstance();

        Field[] fields = ret.getClass().getFields();
        int i = 0;
        for (Field field : fields) {
            field.set(ret, params[i]);
            i++;
        }
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ret;
}

public class person {
    String name;
    String Surname;
    int age;
    String address;
    public person(){}
    public person(String n, String s, int a, String ad) {
        name = n;
        Surname = s;
        age = a;
        address = ad;
    }
}

public class member {
    int person;
    String ID;
    String password;
    String when;
    public member(){}
    public member(int pe, String i, String p, String w) {
        person = pe;
        ID = i;
        password = p;
        when = w;
    }
}
```

My objective is testing java.lang.reflect.

In that example i tryed to create a new istanze of some my classes.
But it not work.
I don't understand what is the error.

i need only modify the fields in my class.

Comment: "But it not work" is not an appropriate error description. Does it crash, fail to compile, return something unexpected?

Comment: We also don't understand what is the error, since you never said what the error says.

Comment: *Unrelated:* Java naming convention states that class names should start with Uppercase letter, so they should be named `Person` and `Member`, and field names should start with lowercase letter, so `surname` and `id`.

Comment: Here is guess of errors: `newClass()` is a non-static method called from a static context. Make it `static`. I also don't see any reason why `Person` and `Member` should be inner classes. Make them `static` too.